# how i can pass html in XML?

Tags: html, xml, sql-server-2008

when i am trying to insert following data into a table in MS-SQL server 2008. it inserting as

**{column1}Contact Information{column2}{column3}Address{column4}{column5}{column6}**

instead of whole html code within the xml tag DecoratorLayout given below. here it treating all html tags as xml tags, how  can  I overcome this problem??

```
<ROOT>
<DecoratorLayout>
    <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">{column1}</div></div><h3 class="form-section">Contact Information</h3><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span5">{column2}</div><div class="span5">{column3}</div></div><h3 class="form-section">Address</h3><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span5">{column4}</div><div class="span5">{column5}</div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">{column6}</div></div>
</DecoratorLayout>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: is your database field of varchar(max) datatype ?

Comment: @sankoobaba yes ofcourse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using CDATA you can achieve

```
<ROOT>
<DecoratorLayout>
  <![CDATA[ <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">{column1}</div></div><h3 class="form-section">Contact Information</h3><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span5">{column2}</div><div class="span5">{column3}</div></div><h3 class="form-section">Address</h3><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span5">{column4}</div><div class="span5">{column5}</div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">{column6}</div></div>]]>
</DecoratorLayout>
</ROOT>
```